# RelativeLayout's attribute alignWithParentIfMissing not giving expected result

Tags: android, layout, android-relativelayout

Thanks in advance for your time. 
I am using RelativeLayout to display my List items. I have image buttons left aligned with Parent and bunch of TextViews on the right of images.
Only text views which will always be Visible are **ordersummaryrow.itemtitle** and **ordersummaryrow.itemprice**. 
I am setting visibility of rest of text views  depending on condition in CustomAdapter. 
For example if special request is supplied then it should be display at the bottom, if item option is supplied then on top of request, if extra item is supplied then on top of item option and finally main item.
Also I would like Main Item Title to be align centrally if none of the other text views are visible like as explained [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-efficiency.html). 
But this is not what I am getting with this row layout. If special request is supplied then thats the only textview I am seeing. It is not even displaying Main Item Title.
I am sure it is do-able and I must be missing something.
Appreciate your help.

ordersummaryrow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/listitem_background"
    >
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ordersummaryrow.buttons"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ordersummaryrow.delete"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/orderdelete"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ordersummaryrow.update"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/orderedit"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout> 
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ordersummaryrow.splrequest"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/custom_black_color"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ordersummaryrow.buttons"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ordersummaryrow.itemoption"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/custom_black_color"
    android:text="Item Option"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ordersummaryrow.buttons"
    android:layout_above="@id/ordersummaryrow.splrequest" 
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ordersummaryrow.extraitem"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/custom_black_color"
    android:text="Extra Item Title"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ordersummaryrow.buttons"
    android:layout_above="@id/ordersummaryrow.itemoption" 
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ordersummaryrow.extraitemprice"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/custom_black_color"
    android:text="$"
    android:layout_above="@id/ordersummaryrow.itemoption" 
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true" 
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ordersummaryrow.itemtitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/custom_black_color"
    android:layout_above="@id/ordersummaryrow.extraitem" 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ordersummaryrow.buttons"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Item Title" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ordersummaryrow.itemprice"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/custom_black_color"
    android:text="$$"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/ordersummaryrow.itemtitle"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is GetView() in custom adapter

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = convertView;
        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)m_context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            try{
                row = vi.inflate(R.layout.ordersummaryrow, null);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.i("SUBMENU", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        OrderSummaryRowViewHolder holder = (OrderSummaryRowViewHolder)row.getTag();
        if(holder == null)
        {
            holder =  new OrderSummaryRowViewHolder(row);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        OrderedItem orderItem = m_orderedItem.get(position);
        if (orderItem != null) 
        {
            if(m_updateListener != null)
                holder.m_updateBtn.setOnClickListener(m_updateListener);
            else
                Log.i("OrderSummaryRowAdapter", "Update Listener is not registered");

            if(m_deleteListener != null)
                holder.m_deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(m_deleteListener);
            else
                Log.i("OrderSummaryRowAdapter", "Delete Listener is not registered");

            holder.m_titleTxt.setText(orderItem.get_orderItem().getName());
            holder.m_priceTxt.setText("$" + (String.valueOf(orderItem.get_orderItem().getPrice())));
            if(orderItem.get_extraItems().size() == 0) //No extra items added so hide corresponding text box
            {
                holder.m_extraItemTxt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.m_extraItemPriceTxt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else
            {
                StringBuilder sbItemName = new StringBuilder();
                StringBuilder sbItemPrice = new StringBuilder();
                for (SubMenu extraItem : orderItem.get_extraItems()) 
                {
                    sbItemName.append(extraItem.getName());
                    sbItemName.append("\n");
                    sbItemPrice.append("$" + (String.valueOf(extraItem.getPrice())));
                    sbItemPrice.append("\n");
                }
                holder.m_extraItemTxt.setText(sbItemName);
                holder.m_extraItemPriceTxt.setText(sbItemPrice);
            }

            if(orderItem.get_options().size() == 0)
                holder.m_optionTxt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            else
            {
                StringBuilder sbOption = new StringBuilder();
                for (ItemOption option : orderItem.get_options()) 
                {
                    sbOption.append(option.getName());
                    sbOption.append("\n");
                }
                holder.m_optionTxt.setText(sbOption);
            }

            if(orderItem.getspecialRequest() != null && 
                    orderItem.getspecialRequest().length() > 0)
                holder.m_splRequestTxt.setText(orderItem.getspecialRequest());
            else
                holder.m_splRequestTxt.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
        return row;
    }
```

Comment: is it about the UI? if so, who cares about the getView ;)? its confusing... the whole post is kinda huuge, i guess you get a fast answer if you describe what kind of layout youre tring to accomplish, draw a dirty bitmap with paint for example

Answer (score 0):

In all your if()..else() statements, add the setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) statements. For eg,

```
if(orderItem.getspecialRequest() != null && 
                orderItem.getspecialRequest().length() > 0){
            holder.m_splRequestTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.m_splRequestTxt.setText(orderItem.getspecialRequest());
        }else{
            holder.m_splRequestTxt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

Similarly for all the rest of our cases.

**Update**

Please try this code and check if it works

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View row = convertView;
    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)m_context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        try{
            row = vi.inflate(R.layout.ordersummaryrow, null);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.i("SUBMENU", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    OrderSummaryRowViewHolder holder = (OrderSummaryRowViewHolder)row.getTag();
    if(holder == null)
    {
        holder =  new OrderSummaryRowViewHolder(row);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    OrderedItem orderItem = m_orderedItem.get(position);
    if (orderItem != null) 
    {
        if(m_updateListener != null)
            holder.m_updateBtn.setOnClickListener(m_updateListener);
        else
            Log.i("OrderSummaryRowAdapter", "Update Listener is not registered");

        if(m_deleteListener != null)
            holder.m_deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(m_deleteListener);
        else
            Log.i("OrderSummaryRowAdapter", "Delete Listener is not registered");

        if(orderItem.getspecialRequest() != null && 
                orderItem.getspecialRequest().length() > 0)
            holder.m_splRequestTxt.setText(orderItem.getspecialRequest());
        else
            holder.m_splRequestTxt.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        if(orderItem.get_options().size() == 0)
            holder.m_optionTxt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        else
        {
            StringBuilder sbOption = new StringBuilder();
            for (ItemOption option : orderItem.get_options()) 
            {
                sbOption.append(option.getName());
                sbOption.append("\n");
            }
            holder.m_optionTxt.setText(sbOption);
        }

        if(orderItem.get_extraItems().size() == 0) //No extra items added so hide corresponding text box
        {
            holder.m_extraItemTxt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.m_extraItemPriceTxt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else
        {
            StringBuilder sbItemName = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder sbItemPrice = new StringBuilder();
            for (SubMenu extraItem : orderItem.get_extraItems()) 
            {
                sbItemName.append(extraItem.getName());
                sbItemName.append("\n");
                sbItemPrice.append("$" + (String.valueOf(extraItem.getPrice())));
                sbItemPrice.append("\n");
            }
            holder.m_extraItemTxt.setText(sbItemName);
            holder.m_extraItemPriceTxt.setText(sbItemPrice);
        }

        holder.m_titleTxt.setText(orderItem.get_orderItem().getName());
        holder.m_priceTxt.setText("$" + (String.valueOf(orderItem.get_orderItem().getPrice())));

    }
    return row;
}
```

Comment: In layout it is visible by default. In GetView I am just hiding it based on condition. Still I gave shot by setting visibility to Visible in code. It didnt work.

Comment: I don't see any logical reason by flipping code (i.e. initializing spl request first and Title last). Though out of curiosity I tried and still didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Well I have noticed at times with layouts (specially relativelayout) that the order matters in certain places. In cases where the position of component A depends on component B and component B is set to GONE. Even though in your case you have mentioned alignwithparent. Can you try it out with just 3 items and then slowly increase to incorporate all the textviews? I couldn't find the time to try that.